# Springboot Upgrade Spring Integration Issue

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have an application with Spring Integration that queues incoming messages in a PriorityChannel which are persisted using a messageStore using MongoDbChannelMessageStore implementation. Currently we are under Springboot 2.1.3 version. And we make all the necessary changes to go to 2.5.4 version. Many changes in build.gradle, AWS package refactor etc, etc... no problem with this and everything works as expected.

The specific problem is that if I want to upgrade having stored incoming messages with the older version in production, when the application with the new version continues to process this load the following error occurrs. Seems to be a convertion from spring integration that goes wrong. Any advice please?

```
2022-01-12 16:41:27,214 [1;31mERROR[0;39m [36m[org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler       catalogue-pool-1         ][0;39m org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [org.bson.types.Binary] to type [org.springframework.messaging.Message<?>] for value 'org.bson.types.Binary@fb62eb16'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -798892522772790821, local class serialVersionUID = 1755438538721305358
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:427)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [org.bson.types.Binary] to type [org.springframework.messaging.Message<?>] for value 'org.bson.types.Binary@fb62eb16'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -798892522772790821, local class serialVersionUID = 1755438538721305358
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doConvert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1546)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doConvert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1538)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1033)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1891)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1640)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$AssociationAwareMongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1689)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$AssociationAwareMongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:269)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:368)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:341)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:273)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3178)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2771)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindAndRemove(MongoTemplate.java:2659)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findAndRemove(MongoTemplate.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbChannelMessageStore.pollMessageFromGroup(MongoDbChannelMessageStore.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupQueue.doPoll(MessageGroupQueue.java:357)
    at org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupQueue.poll(MessageGroupQueue.java:192)
    at org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupQueue.poll(MessageGroupQueue.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel.doReceive(QueueChannel.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.PriorityChannel.doReceive(PriorityChannel.java:138)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractPollableChannel.receive(AbstractPollableChannel.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.receiveMessage(PollingConsumer.java:217)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:444)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:413)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -798892522772790821, local class serialVersionUID = 1755438538721305358
    at org.springframework.integration.support.converter.AllowListDeserializingConverter.convert(AllowListDeserializingConverter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.support.BinaryToMessageConverter.convert(BinaryToMessageConverter.java:38)
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.support.BinaryToMessageConverter.convert(BinaryToMessageConverter.java:31)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:386)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -798892522772790821, local class serialVersionUID = 1755438538721305358
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2001)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1665)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2403)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1665)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2403)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:631)
    at org.springframework.util.MimeType.readObject(MimeType.java:598)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2294)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1665)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:459)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2294)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1665)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2403)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:631)
    at org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders.readObject(MessageHeaders.java:329)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2294)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1665)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2403)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:631)
    at org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders.readObject(MessageHeaders.java:329)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2294)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1665)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2403)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1665)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:459)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.converter.AllowListDeserializingConverter.deserialize(AllowListDeserializingConverter.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.converter.AllowListDeserializingConverter.convert(AllowListDeserializingConverter.java:133)
    ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah... Looks like some `org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap` class internal state has been changed in between and its previously serialized version is not compatible with what a new app is expecting.

You probably need to implement and Adapter application which would be based on an old version of Spring Boot. Offloads those messages, removes (or convert) the header with that `org.springframework.util.MimeType` value and serializes them back to the queue for a new app.

I don't think it really have a significant value to really store the whole  `org.springframework.util.MimeType`, but not just its plain string representation...

Comment: thanks Artem. We are storing the spring integration message, as is, in the mongo messagestore. It is a message that comes from an httpMessagingGateway with a custom business payload that travels along the flow. If we transform it and generate a new one (spring message)  that only keeps the reply channel from the old one just before sending it to the persitent priority channel, the version upgrade works well. There is no serialization error. So I asume that the problem is related to the framework itself.  Your suggestion is fine but for us is a little bit risky due to the application nature.

Comment: The framework cannot help here since this is a standard Java serialization problem where a new class version cannot accept bytes for the old one. I understand that it is a framework fault placing you into this rabbit hole via its out-of-the-box serialization feature by default, but there is no other workarounds unless you can keep somehow `spring-core` dependency in its old version, until you clean up that queue from old messages. For the future I have suggested you to convert that `MimeType` header into its string representation, so no `LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap` serialization is involved.

Comment: The `MongoDbChannelMessageStore` can be configured with a custom `MappingMongoConverter` where you can provide your own `Message` writer and reader. But that's would be handy only in the future version of your app and only with clean MongoDB collection for messages. The old serializaed messages won't be read properly with your new reader: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-message-store

Comment: great Artem, it is pretty clear